# how to show multiple slide at a time in ui.bootstrap carousel

Tags: angularjs, carousel, multiple-instances, ui.bootstrap

I am using [ui.bootstrap carousel](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel).It's working fine but I need 3 images to show in a  slide at a time and then slide one by one.

Comment: Be aware that your plunker is empty. I hope you do not expect of us to implement the task for you. Moreover your question is quite ambiguous. What do you mean by _3 slides to show at a time_? 3 Image pictures on one slide?

Comment: sorry for that. yes 3 image pictures in one slide

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted the example from their plunker to match your needs. Please check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/c6BWDGS44c9PNejCZXac?p=preview).

The important bits are:

```
<img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;" ng-if="!slide.images">
<div ng-if="slide.images">
      <img src="{{image.url}}" ng-repeat="image in slide.images">
</div>
```

and

```
$scope.slides.push({
    images: [
      {
        url: 'https://unsplash.it/600/100'
      },{
        url: 'https://unsplash.it/600/100'
      },{
        url: 'https://unsplash.it/600/100'
      }
    ],
    text: '3 pictures on one slide',
    id: currIndex++
});
```